# github: how to make it so that the clone project tree is one level deeper?

Tags: git, github, subdirectory

I have a local software project under /PT. When I commit code to githib it gets commited as project-1.9 and inside that it creates the PT directory.

I want to make it so that when someone clones the project https://github.com/company/project-1.9.git it will clone into a local directory PT and not into project-1.9/PT

Does anyone know of a way to do this? there a way to do this?

Comment: what is the url when you use HTTPS clone URL button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that repo `project-1.9` has only the `PT` folder, one way would be to reorganize the data with:

```
cd /local/clone/of/project-1.9
git mv PT/* .
git rm PT/
git commit -m "Move everything on top root folder of the repo"
git push
```

Then a  `git clone https://github.com/company/project-1.9.git PT` would clone everything in a `PT` local folder .

---

But if `PT` is just one of many root folders within `project-1.9`, then it is best to:

- [isolate `PT` in its own repo](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)
- add `PT` as a submodule in the `project-1.9` repo.

Since `PT` would be its own repo, it could be cloned directly:

```
git clone https://github.com/company/PT
```

That would give you a `PT` folder with `PT` content directly.